# clean url using mod_rewirte

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

How i can convert this url

```
www.domain.com/post.php?view=36&title=slug-of-post-title
```

into clean url as

```
www.domain.com/36-slug-of-post-title
```

Help me, if you know where i can get a better understanding about mod_rewrite please provide website address

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule   ^([0-9]+)-(.*)$  /post.php?view=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]

http://www.4webhelp.net/tutorials/misc/mod_rewrite.php

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-(.*)$ post.php?view=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` is a feature of Apache.  Similar modules exist for other web servers such as lighttpd, nginx, tornado, etc.  As usual, RTM applies here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

For the URL you asked about, you may want to do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase   /

#  now the rewriting rules
RewriteRule   ^([0-9]+)-(.*)$  post.php?view=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

What the rule above does is match any URL in your domain starting with / (see `RewriteBase`), followed by at least one digit (`([0-9]+)`), followed by anything, to the appropriate place.

Please see the link above for more information about mod_rewrite.