# mod_rewriter change my url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have some problems with mod_rewrited at .httacess.

We have created a website, the website links have this sctructure.

```
www.myweb.com/page.php?title=this-is-the-title&filmID=454122
AND
www.myweb.com/video.php?title=this-is-the-title&filmID=2567971&player=veevr
AND
www.myweb.com/gallery/index.php?galeriID=11
```

is possible to change this structure to:

```
www.myweb.com/page/this-is-the-title/454122.html

www.myweb.com/video/this-is-the-title/454122/veevr.html

www.myweb.com/gallery/index/11.html
```

Any help will be really great
Thank you for reading the post!
Best Regards
JoinOG

Comment: possible duplicate of [clean url using mod_rewirte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357345/clean-url-using-mod-rewirte)

Comment: i have just created it, please help to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess file in your web root folder put the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+).html/?$ page.php?title=$1&filmID=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^video/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+).html/?$ video.php?title=$1&filmID=$2&player=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^gallery/index/([0-9]+).html/?$ gallery/index.php?galeriID=$1 [L]
```

What this does is mask the url `/page/something/12345.html` to `page.php?title=something&filmID=12345`. It masks it, so when you go to the first URL it still looks like the first URL in the address bar but is really at the second URL. Simple tutorial on how this works is here: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

The server will think you are in the folder `/page/something/` so if your CSS, images and hyperlinks are locally relative links they will not work, e.g. it will look in `/page/something/yourimage.png` for an image linked to like this `<img src='yourimage.png'/>`. To get it to work as you'd like it to, you'll need to put a forward slash before all your links to make it relative to your website's root folder like this `<img src='/yourimage.png'/>`.

Comment: hello, i am trying it, but when i click on the old adres it dons not redirect on the new adres, also css and images cant be seen

Comment: also, i cant get the values from title for example with $_GET['title'] etc , how can i fix this ?

Comment: @Tim When you give an answer try to explain "how it works". And the question looks like a duplicate one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357345/clean-url-using-mod-rewirte

Comment: @JoinOG mod_rewrite masks the 'new' address to the old one, not the other way around so if you go to gallery/index/123.html it will display as that url in the address bar but you will actually be at the location gallery/index.php?galeriID=123. I've added some more detail which may help you.