# Mod_rewrite change url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created custom Wordpress archive page gumball.php which can handle multiple categories or tags based on URL.

For example:

```
xyz.com/categories/gumball.php?categories=category1+category2
```

will display archive of posts categorized as category 1 and category 2

```
xyz.com/tags/gumball.php?tags=tag1+tag2
```

will display archive of posts tagged as tag 1 and tag 2

Now I'm stuck with htaccess mod_rewrite to have those URLs changed to something like using method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878999/mod-rewriter-change-my-url)

```
xyz.com/categories/gumball/category1+category2 
xyz.com/tags/gumball/tag1+tag2
```

as follow

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^categories/gumball/?$ gumball.php?categories=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tags/gumball/?$ gumbal.php?tags=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^categories/gumball/(.*)$ /categories/gumball.php?categories=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tags/gumball/(.*)$ /tags/gumball.php?tags=$1 [L]
```

but make sure they're *before* any wordpress rules you already have in your document root.